# Google Analytics with First Party Cookie

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I am in the process of setting up Google Analytics (GA) on a Wordpress site. As part of this, I want to include a custom cookie (for users that consent) that allows me to segment the analytics of users based on what settings they have active on the site (via a custom plugin). I have managed to successfully implement this most of the way (the cookie is included in many of the tagged events).

However, I have included the custom cookie in a Gravity Form that is being submitted on the website, and there are a number of instances of a form being submitted successfully, tagged with a cookie ID, but that cookie ID is not showing up in Google Analytics as an option to segment page views, for example. I have a record of the cookie being generated on my Apache server, but it has not made its way through to GA.

Is there a way to see all events with a specific attribute in GA? Or is this only possible with a custom report (which necessarily requires you to filter out events that don't have a specific metric).

(I'm primarily a back-end developer, and have limited experience with GA. Apologies if there is something very obvious that I have not done.)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a [custom dimension in Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en&ref_topic=2709827), retrieve the cookie value and [pass it to the GA code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) (how exactly would depend on the version of the GA code that you use, as they have recently shifted from the analytics.js library to gtag.js).

Comment: Thanks Eike. I had done this, and I am able to see the custom dimension in some the reports, but I'm not seeing all of the events, as my Gravity form submissions indicate (my guess is around 50%).